# Opencart : How can change URL of all my site to SEO frindly

Tags: opencart2.x

I'm using Opencart 2.x version.

Seo urls not works and my links like information/information_id=1

I supposed that it should be changed automatically, but not. All site's links for product, categories and infromation pages had been changed, but that added by me manually - NOT. Can anyone halp me and answer why ?

Comment: http://themes.eshopalot.com/enable-seo-friendly-urls-in-opencart/

Comment: thank you alot ...